# Karate: skip calls to external/third party service

Tags: karate

I have an API that calls other external/third party services. Is it possible to skip calling external/third party services when API is called using feature file?

NA

NA

NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, no because Karate has no control over how your API is implemented.

But maybe you are looking for Karate test-doubles: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty

With that what you can do is this:

- write a mock that simulates the external / third-party service
- configure the API you own to call the mock (on `localhost`) instead of the external URL
- run normal Karate tests on your API. you should be able to do the configuration and starting the mock automatically as part of your test set-up, see: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#embedding